# Custom Vision: Out of upload quota

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I have two projects on the F0 tier. This morning they both will not let me upload additional images

```
150 training images uploaded; 0 remain
```

and

```
1162 training images uploaded; 0 remain
```

The documenation says the limit should be 5,000.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/limits-and-quotas

Comment: Can you please add more details about the region.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue for F0 limit. Basically recently we have done a pretty big backend change and just deployed that. So this deployment caused the regression. The setting for F0 limit of projects are set wrong.

We Will deploy the fix as soon as possible.